# Forms and security - salting passwords and CSRF

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Am I right in thinking that password salting is all taken care of in larval? i.e. it's automatic?

Also I was wondering about a log in form and CSRF. Is it wise to include this on any forms that I post data with, i.e. a log in form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that password salting is automatic in Laravel. Prior to storing a user's password in your database, you should be encrypting it using Hash::make($password) which uses PHP's secure [BCrypt hashing algorithm](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (which, in this case, generates a salt automatically).

In response to your second question, if you create a form using the Blade syntax, then a CSRF token is automatically inserted into your form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'login)) }}
    // A CSRF token will exist in a hidden text input
{{ Form::close() }}
```

If you choose to generate your form without using Blade, then you're required to attach the CSRF token automatically to your form, using Form::token();.

However, with either method, you still need to apply a filter to any routes which Laravel needs to validate the token on. In the above example, the form will POST to the named route 'login', so we need to apply the CSRF token 'before' filter to that route:

```
Route::post('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin', 
'before' => 'csrf'));
```

Comment: Great, clear answer, just one more thing, would you recommend using CSRF for log in forms and general POST forms?

Comment: You should use it whenever the submission would cause a state change on the server or expose sensitive information. So likely yes for a login form, but for general post forms it depends, e.g. yes for a change of password but not absolutely necessary for a search form (but what's the harm in using it anyway?)

Comment: Yeah, similar to what @petercoles said, whenever a request doesn't cause any modification on the server it _might_ be okay to leave it out, but the fact that it's _so_ trivial to implement in Laravel and has minimal overhead, you really have no excuse not to use it. Laravel makes it even easier to apply a CSRF filter across multiple routes with [route groups](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already does that for your if you use:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    //
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Take a look at the generated HTML, you'll see a crsf token on it. And then you just have to add the check to your routes:

```
Route::post('myform', ['before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'MyController@update']);
```

Laravel will throw an exception if the csrf token doesn't match.